# How to decide the convergence or divergence of a positive term series under the given information?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Positive series problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131678/positive-series-problem)

If $a_n > 0$ for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$ such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges, then how to determine if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$ converges or diverges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_n$ does not tend to $0$, then clearly $\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ also doesn't tend to $0$ and hence the series diverges.

If $a_n \to 0$, then we can lower-bound $\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ by $c a_n$, where $c$ is a constant. (I will let you fill in the details.) Hence, again by comparison test $a_n$ diverges.

Equivalently, you could directly use the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: I've managed to fill in the details. So nice of you!

Answer (score 0):

You have ${x\over 1 + x} \le x$ for all $x\ge 0$.  That will give you a start.

Comment: Your remark is useful only if the series $\sum a_n$ *converges*.

Comment: Yes, but you see the original series Diverges.

Comment: The series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n {a_n/(1 + a_n)}$ will converge or diverge together.