# Suppose $x_n \ge 0$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_n+1}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

One thing I notice we can do is say $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x_n}$ but I am not sure how this helps. By Cauchy criteria we can also say there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}  \frac{x_n}{x_n+1}| < \epsilon.$ Could I use these here? I see the direction from right to left is limit comparison test, but what about left to right?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{1+x_n}=\frac{1}{x_n}\cdot \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}\to 1$$

if $x_n\to 0$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positive series problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131678/positive-series-problem)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the duplicate, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $$0 \le \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}\le x_n,\\
\sum {x_n}<\infty\Rightarrow \sum \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}<\infty 
$$

Now suppose that $\sum \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}<\infty $.

$\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}\to 0$, and so $x_n\to 0$, so there is a $N$ such as 
$
n>N\Rightarrow x_n<1
$
and then$$ 
\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}>\frac {x_n}2
$$so $$
\sum \frac{x_n}{1+x_n}<\infty \Rightarrow \sum {x_n}<\infty
$$

Comment: That's what I did as well, what about left to right direction?

Comment: But $x_n$ is greater than or equal to $x_n/(1+x_n)$.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance bounding the sum means convergence?

Comment: If $x_n$ is positive yes lol. Monotone convergence theorem

Comment: This looks good. I know its seems obvious, but how can can we be rigorous about $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n} \to 0$ implies $x_n \to 0$? Proof by contradiction?

Comment: if $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n} < r$ then $x_n < r + rx_n$ then $x_n < \frac{r}{1-r}$.

Answer (score 4):

For the other way:

Hint: If $\sum\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$ converges, then in particular $x_n$ must converge to $0$, and in particular there exists a constant $C\geq0$ such that $x_n\leq C$. Then 
$$\sum\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}\geq\sum\frac{x_n}{1+C}.$$