# If $\sum a_n$ diverges, prove that $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

And suppose that $a_n > 0\quad \forall n$. Since the case $b_n := \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \to p$ with $p \ne 0$ is clear, I'm supposing that $b_n\to 0$ and that $\sum b_n$ converges.

So for any real $M > 0$ I have that there's a natural $N$ such that $n\ge N \implies$ $$1+\frac{1}{a_n}>M$$

I feel that there's a way to limit $a_n$ by $b_n$ so that convergence of $\sum b_n$ implies the contradiction that $\sum a_n$ converges. But I'm getting nothing from these hypothesis.

Comment: I think  one of the statements in your title is backwards

Comment: Let $a_n=n^2-1$. Then $\sum a_n$ diverges but $\sum\frac{1}{1+a_n}$ converges.

Comment: It's $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$, I corrected it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131678/321264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a_n\not\to0$, then ${a_n\over1+a_n}\not\to0$.  If $a_n\to0$ (and $a_n\ge0$), then ${a_n\over1+a_n}\gt{a_n\over2}$ for all large $n$.  In either case $\sum{a_n\over1+a_n}$ diverges.

Comment: I didn't understand how you got $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} > \frac{a_n}{2}$ from $a_n \to 0$ and $a_n>0$.

Comment: @FryanBury, if $a_n\to0$, then $a_n\lt1$ for large $n$, and if $0\le a_n\lt1$, then $1/(1+a_n)\gt1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $2$ cases to consider:

$a)$ The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, which means $|a_n| < M$ for some $M > 0$. Thus $\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}> \dfrac{a_n}{1+M}$, and $\sum_{n}\dfrac{1} {1+M}a_n$ diverges to $+\infty$, hence $\sum_{n}\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ diverges to $+\infty$

$b)$ The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded, thus for each $k \ge 1$, we can find a term $a_{n_k}$ such that $a_{n_k}> k\implies \sum_{n}\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n} \ge \sum_{k}\dfrac{a_{n_k}}{1+a_{n_k}} > \sum_{k}\dfrac{k}{1+k} > \sum_{k}\dfrac{1}{k} = +\infty$

In either case, we find that the series in question diverges by comparison with a diverging series.

Comment: Minor quibble:  You want the $n_k$'s to be distinct, e.g, $n_1\lt n_2\lt n_3\lt\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

**asymptotic comparison**

If $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0$ then

$$a_n\sim \frac {a_n}{1+a_n} \;\;(n\to+\infty) $$

so the two series have the same nature.