# If $\sum u_n$ be a divergent series of positive reals, then $\sum \frac{u_n}{1+u_n}$ diverges also

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, divergent-series

Although this question has been posted here many times, I am posting it again in order to get my proof verified.

Firstly, we break up the index set of $(u_n)_n$ into a partition of two sets $A$ and $B$ such that:

$A= \{n\in \mathbb{N}:u_n<1\}$ and $B=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: u_n \ge 1 \}$.

Now, $u_n<1 \implies u_n +1<2 \implies \displaystyle\frac{u_n}{2}<\frac{u_n}{1+u_n} $. Taking summation over $A \ \ $,

$\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{n \in A}u_n < \sum_{n \in A} \frac{u_n}{1+u_n} ...(1)$

Again, $u_n \geq 1 \implies 2u_n\geq1+ u_n \implies \displaystyle\frac{u_n}{1+u_n} \ge \frac{1}{2}  $

The sum over $B$ becomes  $\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle |B| \le \sum_{n \in B} \frac{u_n}{1+u_n} ...(2)$ [$|B|$ denotes the number of elements in $B$].

Since $A$ and $B$ form a partition of $\mathbb{N}$, then either of them (or both) must be an infinite set.

Three cases may arise:

\begin{cases}
 A \mathbb{\ is \ infinite \ but}  B \mathbb{ \ is \ finite} \\
 B \mathbb{\ is \ infinite \ but}  A \mathbb{ \ is \ finite} \\
\mathbb {both \ are \ infinite}
\end{cases}

In the first, second and third cases, the left hand sides of $1$, $2$, &  $1 { \ \mathbb{and} \ } 2$ diverges respectively. In any case,  $\sum \frac{u_n}{1+u_n}$ diverges.

Please verify this method. It will be of immense help for me.

Comment: I found out later (after posting it) that this proof almost goes along the same line:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2794447/389992

Comment: if $\sum_n \frac{u_n}{1+u_n} < \infty$, then $\frac{u_n}{1+u_n} \to 0$, so $u_n \to 0$, so $\frac{u_n}{1+u_n} \ge \frac{1}{2}u_n$ for large $n$, so $\sum_n \frac{u_n}{1+u_n}$ diverges by comparison test

Comment: That's a bit simpler...

Comment: More  solutins e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131678/42969.

Answer (score 1):

I'm transferring @mathworker21's solution into an answer, so I'll make this CW.

If $\sum \dfrac{u_n}{1+u_n} < \infty$, then $\dfrac{u_n}{1+u_n} \to 0$, so $u_n \to 0$, so $\dfrac{u_n}{1+u_n} \ge \frac12 u_n$ for $n$ sufficienty large, so $\sum \dfrac{u_n}{1+u_n}$ diverges by comparison test.

Comment: How do you make CW @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會

Comment: @MariaMazur There's a checkbox at the right bottom corner.  Just tick that will do.

Comment: aha, thanks @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Answer (score 0):

(Proof 1).  (i).   If $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=0$ then $u_n<1/2$ for all but finitely many $n.$ So $u_n/(1 +u_n)\ge u_n/(1+1/2)=(2/3)u_n$ for all but finitely many $n.$

(ii).  If $\neg (\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=0\}$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $u_n>r$ for infinitely many $n.$ And $u_n>r>0 \implies u_n/(1+u_n)>r/(1+r).$ So $\neg (\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n/(1+u_n)=0).$

(Proof 2).  Let $v_n=u_n/(1+u_n),$ so $u_n=v_n/(1-v_n).$ The Q is equivalent to:  If $0\le v_n<1$ for all $n$ and $\sum_nv_n$ converges then $\sum_nv_n/(1-v_n)$ converges. Proof: $\lim_{n\to \infty}v_n=0$ so for all but finitely many $n$ we have $v_n<1/2.$ So $v_n/(1-v_n)\le v_n/(1-1/2)=2v_n $ for all but finitely many $n$.