# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n}$ diverge

Tags: real-analysis

Suggestion of how to do it, please.

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a succession in $\mathbb R  ^+$ such that  $\sum a_n$ diverges, and if  $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_k}$. Show that 
>   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{ \frac {a_n}{1+a_n}}$ diverge.

Please.thank

Comment: what's the point in the definition of $s_n$

Comment: if $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$ which implies $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \ge \frac{1}{2}a_n$ for $n$ large, so compare to $\sum a_n$ which diverges

Comment: $s_n$ is is the limit of the succession of sums

Comment: I specifically asked you what the point of defining it is. You didn't give an answer, presumably because there is no point to defining it. Also, my second problem gives a proof of your problem statement

Comment: You can see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131678/positive-series-problem-sum-limits-n-geq1a-n-infty-implies-sum-n-geq1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem** Suppose that we have two series $ \Sigma_n a_n $ and $\Sigma_n b_n$ with $ a_n\geq 0, b_n > 0 $ for all $ n$. Then if $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = c$ with $ 0 < c < \infty $ then either both series converge or both series diverge..

$\displaystyle  \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{a_n}{\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}} = a_n+1 \to 1 $ as $a_n \to 0$. If $a_n \not \to 0$ then the second series clearly diverges.

Comment: ...need some check i think

Comment: Wrong answer. It is not true that $a_n \leq \frac {a_n} {a_n+1}$

Comment: I've edited it now. My edit is actually the same as @JRen post, so I'd rather delete this, but I can't as it has been accepted.

Comment: @vera please un-accept this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a_n\to0$; otherwise $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\not\to0$. Then since $$\frac{a_n}{\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}}\to1,$$by ratio test, these two series share the convergence result.

Comment: Just realised that my edited version is exactly what you have written. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine. Not a hard problem :)

Comment: I know this is old, but doesn't a ratio-test equaling one mean that the test is inconclusive?